# JSON data through JS/AJAX into PHP

Tags: javascript, php, json, ajax

**Goal:**
I'm using the coinmarketcap.com API [(link)](https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/?convert=EUR). ***Beforehand*** I got their data into PHP. Sample:

```
<?php
$url = "https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/?convert=EUR";
$response = file_get_contents($url);
$obj = json_decode($response,true);
print_r($obj);
?>
```

Now I want to use AJAX/JS to get live data. I now got the following JS code:

```
<p id="collect"></p>
<script>
function loadDoc() {
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        var obj = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
        document.getElementById("collect").innerHTML = obj;
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", "https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/?convert=EUR" + Math.random(), true);
  xhttp.send();
}

(function() {
   loadDoc()
})();
setInterval ( "loadDoc()", 5000 );
</script>
```

**Output:**

```
[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]
```

^ the output. I also tried the above code without the JSON.parse but it gave me one string of everything.

**Question:** How can I get the above live data back into a PHP array? I'm quite the newbie to this but I have tried for several days.

Comment: Should it not instead be `JSON.stringify()`? You're trying to insert a JSON object into HTML, which is definitely going to break!

Comment: "_back into a PHP array_" Why, you're on JS ..?

Comment: @MattFletcher stringify returns a string and includes a lot of "\n" and such. I thought of outputting it all on the page so my PHP could collect it. Any suggestions on how I should do it instead?

Comment: You've got your encodings backwards. You need to `json_encode` in your php, such that it is a JSON string, and NOT a php object. Then simply echo it out (Not using `print_r`). Then on your client script, you don't need to do anything. Use json.Parse if you intend to process the json as an object (I assume you do), but if you just want the json simply replace your innerHTML with the json string you get from the server.

Comment: I can't say I understand what "PHP could collect it" means. But you can use `obj.replace('\n', '<br/>')` if you want to htmlify the string. JSON isn't naturally pretty-able

Comment: @Teemu My site uses PHP and I got a PHP array which I later want to compare some of the values with.

Comment: But yes, what Sam says. You should be using `json_encode()`

Comment: There's no browser running PHP. If you're getting a PHP array, you should handle all the data loading at server-side.

Comment: @Teemu That makes sense. In my question under the goal section I got a short script where all the collected data was stored in an PHP array, however this data is not live so I have to keep refreshing the page. Do you have a suggestion on how I could display their live data in a PHP array? Because that's essentially what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: The only way to handle the data with PHP would be to send it to your server with another AJAX call, but that wouldn't make much of sense. After took a look at the data you receive, it looks like you're getting a decent JSON string. Just parse it and iterate through to create HTML elements with the desired content. Something like Erik has answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Writing data back to PHP is not possible afaik because PHP is evaluated on serverside and the client just gets its resulting page.
But here is a solution with JavaScript, which is only running on the client side:

As you should know your result looks something like this:

```
[
{
    "id": "bitcoin", 
    "name": "Bitcoin", 
    "symbol": "BTC", 
    "rank": "1", 
    "price_usd": "17391.5", 
    "price_btc": "1.0", 
    "24h_volume_usd": "15047800000.0", 
    "market_cap_usd": "291076752838", 
    "available_supply": "16736725.0", 
    "total_supply": "16736725.0", 
    "max_supply": "21000000.0", 
    "percent_change_1h": "-0.14", 
    "percent_change_24h": "3.75", 
    "percent_change_7d": "45.85", 
    "last_updated": "1513104255", 
    "price_eur": "14834.288623", 
    "24h_volume_eur": "12835201583.6", 
    "market_cap_eur": "248277409254"
}, 
....
]
```

It's an Array of objects where each object contains the following properties (id, name, symbol, ... , market_cap_eur).

To display all those you would need to loop through the array and create some kind of dispalytemplate for the objects.

Therefore you should replace the following line of code in the registered onreadystatechange-function:

```
document.getElementById("collect").innerHTML = obj;
```

with something like:

```
var objlength = obj.length;
var element = document.getElementById("collect");
element.innerHTML = "";
for ( var i = 0; i < objlength; i++){
    element.innerHTML += JSON.stringify(obj[i])+"<br />";
}
```

This would create a stringified result for each cryptocurrency in a new line.
The result of it will still be unreadable and the code to setup the innerHTML is really dirty.
To enhance atleast the display even more, you could do something like:

```
var objlength = obj.length;
var element = document.getElementById("collect");
element.innerHTML = "";
for ( var i = 0; i < objlength; i++){
    element.innerHTML += obj[i].name+" is "+ obj[i].price_eur +"<br />";
}
```

which should return the name of the curreny and the current EUR price per line.
You can extend this by all desired properties.

But as mentioned it's quick and dirty and please don't judge me by this code.

Also you need to delete the + Math.Random() in you request.
Here is a working live example: http://plnkr.co/edit/aHXFVAjH6qoKk2vmOf0u?p=preview

Comment: Thank you very much for your input. In my first script of my question I had their data in a PHP array. However this data wasn't live (had to refresh manually). Do you have a suggestion how I could get their live data through a PHP array?

Comment: @derrtyones Sorry i'm no php developer, but in my honest opinion it's not the purpose of PHP to write values periodically back to it's datamodel. It is an extremly fast Webdevelopment language that will be evaluated on the server and is therefore hard to hack. What do you want to achieve in the end with the array in PHP?

Comment: You're correct. Your example is also teaching me a lot and I believe I can now make progress. I also have some data stored in a MySQL database (for example how many coins of a specific crypto a certain user owns). I want to use that data with the data we just collected through JS.

Comment: @derrtyones actually you could do something pretty dirty. You could force with javascript to reload the PHP-webpage each 5 second and use your current PHP code to retrieve and write the data to SQL. Here is the Javascript function to reload location.reload();.

Answer (score 0):

PHP CODE

```
<?php
$url = "https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/?convert=EUR";
$response = file_get_contents($url);
echo $response;
?>
```

Because the URL returns JSON data, already

Comment: This returns all the data on my page. Now let's say I want to loop through this data to print specific values? For instance, the name of Bitcoin?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. You can use `json_decode` function to decode JSON and then **foreach** loop to loop through the result.